# Google play services lib 9.0 and higher

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

From where i can download google play services lib 9.0 and higher. I need to implement rewarded video ads and updated the sdk to revision 33 but can't find the lib project there .

Answer (score 1):

Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services. For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    }
```

Comment: I need to add this in eclipse

Comment: Check lib in this location <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/

Comment: there is no libproject folder

Comment: Check sdk-location/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.1. It seems like Google broke down the library folder into individual folders. Extract jar from the aar format found in this location.

Comment: There is no lib folder in google play services? Support library eclipse library project is no longer updated? Holy crap, android in eclipse is finally dead, praise the lord.

Comment: @FebiMathew: You cannot "extract jar from the aar format" for most AAR artifacts, as the code in those artifacts will expect the assets, resources, and manifest entries from the AAR to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Google has not been supporting Eclipse for nearly a year. There are no further distributions of support libraries, including Play Services, that can be consumed by the old ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Either move to Android Studio, move to some other IDE that supports AAR artifacts, or leave your existing Play Services alone.